cash register project freeCodeCamp
In the following code, the highlighted part does not get cleared. Although I have checked every element and type of element.Please suggest correction
function changeReturn() {
  let price = 1.87;
let cid = [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];
  const cashInput = Number(document.getElementById("cash").value);
  const changeDue = document.getElementById("change-due");
  const cashRegister = document.getElementById("cash-register");

const balance = cashInput - price;

console.log(typeof cashInput)
console.log(cashInput)
console.log(typeof price)
console.log(price)
console.log(typeof balance)

 
 if (price>cashInput) {
alert("Customer does not have enough money to purchase the item");
  } else if (balance === 0) {
    changeDue.innerText = "No change due - customer paid with exact cash";
  }
}

const purchaseBtn = document.getElementById("purchase-btn");
purchaseBtn.addEventListener("click", changeReturn);

I have tried placing or || condition with isNan(cashInput) and also even if the cashInput === 0 but nothing is resolving freeCodeCamp condition to clear if the user does not have enough funds to purchase the item

You are not handling the case
if (balance < 0)

Thank you. It did not work as the number balance was generating was a string value and had to be parsed before processing through condition and after parsing and floating it worked just fine.
